# Doubt about limit point

Tags: general-topology

I came though this definition about limit point

> A point z is a limit point for a set A if every open set U containing z
>   intersects A in a point other than z.

I want to know can we change it to

> A point z is a limit point for a set A if every open set U containing z
>   intersects A.

Because I couldn't think of any case that open set only intersect A at 1 point. If there is actually this situation, can you please give me example?

Comment: Define set A as some discrete points in the space, with the distance d be normal distance. Then any small enough open set contain $z$ will intersect with A at only $z$

Comment: Open set sometimes can be just 1 point because of the definition. It doesn't "look like open set", but it's an open set, indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}$: $A := \{ \pi \}$.  Every open neighbourhood of $\pi$ intersects $A$, but no open neighbourhood of $\pi$ intersects $A$ at a point other than $\pi$.

Note that your proposed definition is equivalent to saying that $x \in \overline{A}$ (or $x$ is a *point of closure* of $A$), which is a weaker condition.

(In the wild, this is how it happens: given a T<sub>1</sub>-space $X$ and a subset $A \subseteq X$, if $x \in \overline{A}$ (*i.e.*, every open neighbourhood of $x$ meets $A$) and some open neighbourhood of $x$ meets $A$ in exactly one point, then actually $x \in A$, and $x$ is that one point.  Such points are called *isolated points* of $A$.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$.  Then every open neighborhood of $2$ intersects $A$, but many open neighborhods of $2$ intersect $A$ only in that they contain $2$ as a member.  $2$ is not a limit point of $A$.